# How to rename any given file name in specific folder with file name of my choice?

Tags: batch-file

I will have a situation soon where a file(s) will be automatically processed with a specific graphic (pre-press, .pdf files) software BUT a client(s) will be naming file(s) as they waht rather than sticking to the rules or suggestions. I will process the files, muti-page files will be separated (page splitting) into a single-page PDF files. After the whole process I'd like to rename those single-page PDF files to my needs when they end up in my final folder (my "OUT" hot-foldedr). I suppose it's good to mention that my software can handle .bat files. My hot-folder is on server so I believe that exact path have to be included. Or not? Server is Win 2008 SR2. Hmmm, what else could be important. Probably that's all at this moment.

Since I'm not a programmer can somebody please PLEASE help me with a .bat file solution? Please?

So, whatever the filename comes into my "IN" hot-folder will be processed and it will end up in some "OUT" hot-folder. When those processed files pops in that "OUT" folder I'd like them to be renamed according to my taste.

**Example: "any_filename.pdf"  -->  "TEST-XX-DD-MM.pdf"**

This "any_filename.pdf" should be renamed to "TEST-XX-DD-MM.pdf" and stay in that same folder.

I will automate my software further from there to send an e-mail to a client, send files further to a different process etc. This renaming is what gives me a headache now and I don't know did I mention, can this script be executed by itself? I have an option to put a module which is pointing (saying) my software to take a look at the script (if there's any) when files are in specific folder, execute (do your stuff) and leave files there. From there on I will handle this with no problem.

Thank you all for your time and patience and I'm really hoping I'm at the right place and someone will dig this, check out this post and help me out.

Big thanx to all once again!!!

Krešo

Comment: XX should be incrementing number in case there more files for a day?

Comment: Nope, this "XX" is just something it should be in a filename. It's a page numbering to be exact. To be now 100% on point, my software makes "_01.pdf" at the end of a filename. So, when I split a multi-page PDF every Page gets it's own numberin. First is _01, second is _02, etc...

Comment: If you're only processing one file per day, then it's feasible.

Comment: Nope. Yes. Don't know. I think it's worthy doing that to auto-rename stuff in the back without my intervention and by naming files according to my needs.